# Find the failing component given an error message

Tags: ssis

I have an error message:

```
"component "Custodian" (121)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA"
```

The language seems clear enough.  A component called `Custodian (121)` has failed because the metedata is bad.  I'm guessing that a table or view or something has been changed and the component no longer works with it.

If I'm correct in that assumption then that just leaves me with the problem of identifying what the actual component in my IDE is.  There doesn't seem to be anything called `Custodian (121)`.

How to I match up this error with an actual component in the IDE?

Comment: how are you executing the package? if it's Integration services you can look execution reports. It has very detailed info.